# Integrating smart contract with tweet

Tags: solidity, external-api

Is there a way to get a user to send out a tweet once an action on a smart contract happens without doing it on the server-side? And for the tweet to be sent out exactly once?
For example, listening for an event off the contract on the client side and then getting the user to send out a tweet via an embedded link (but this wouldn't guarantee the user being able to send out the tweet only once).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case. You can emit event and read it offchian to and prompt user to send tweet but If you don't have backend you can't track which users have already sent the tweet.

But I'm wondering if you don't have backend where are you storing the user information who will send the tweet?

however, skipping the above question considering that somehow you manage it, there can be approach that'll help you if you have less number of users. What you can do is get the array of users or user that are only meant to send the tweet in function as parameter and send it back in event. Read that event offchain and get the users information from event and send the tweet for expected users only. But you'll have to pass user tracking info every time that function is called.